# Capturing the character before the regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a quick question about a regex that I wrote in JavaScript. It is the following `(?<=,)(.*)(?=:)` and it captures everything between `,` and `:`. I want it, however, to capture the comma itself too, as in.

`So,<< this is what my regex captures at the moment>>: end` would become

`So<<, this is what my regex captures at the moment>>: end`.

I tried using a `.` before the `,` in the regex but it doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: Like https://regex101.com/r/evg4kf/1? Or https://regex101.com/r/evg4kf/2.

Comment: Perhaps `,[^:]+` or if you want to use the capturing group `(,.*?):`

Answer (score 0):

Use a simple capturing group - it's shorter than your current regex and works perfectly:

```js
var regex = /(,.*?):/g;
var string = "So,<< this is what my regex captures at the moment>>: end";
console.log(string.match(regex));
```

Explanation:

`()` - denotes a capturing group
`,` - match a comma
`.?*` - match any amount of any characters
`:` - match a comma

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the double arrows are for indicating the start and the end what your current pattern matches, you could match the comma and then 1+ times not a comma using a negated character class:

```
,[^:]+
```

If the comma at the end should be there, you could use the capturing group:

```
(,[^:]+):
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/iNTmj8/1)

You can omit the positive lookahead `(?=:)` by just matching the colon because you are already using a capturing group to get the match.

```js
const regex = /(,[^:]+):/;
const str = `So,<< this is what my regex captures at the moment>>: end`;
let res = str.match(regex);
console.log(res[1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

As you said :

> So,<< this is what my regex captures at the moment>>: end would become
>   So<<, this is what my regex captures at the moment>>: end.

you could use `replace` like this :

```js
var str = `So,<< this is what my regex captures at the moment>>: end`;
var replace = str.replace(/(.*?)(,)(<<)(.*)/,"$1$3$2$4");
console.log(replace);
```